# What is the de Sitter temperature as of now?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, temperature, cosmic-microwave-background, unit-conversion

It is claimed that [de Sitter temperature](http://www.google.com/#q=de+Sitter+temperature) is $$T=\frac{1}{2\pi}H,$$

where $H$ is the Hubble constant. I presume it is expressed in natural units with which I am not familiar. So what it will be in Kelvins? Is it higher than the temperature of CMB? If so, is there any heat exchange between the both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give the answer with the general method even though a much straightforward way would be to guess the result because it is simple.

The unit of $H$ is the inverse of time denoted by $[\mathrm T^{-1}]$. The dimension of a temperature is denoted by $[\Theta]$. To find the numerical value of $T$ in kelvin, one should find a combination of $c:[\mathrm{LT^{-1}}]$, $\hbar=[\mathrm{ML^2T^{-1}}]$, $\mathcal G:[\mathrm{M^{-1}L^3T^{-2}}]$ and $k_{\mathrm B}:[\mathrm{ML^2T^{-2}\Theta^{-1}}]$ ($[\mathrm L]$ and $[\mathrm M]$ represent length and mass respectively) such that
$$ c^x \;\hbar^y \;\mathcal G ^z\; k_{\mathrm B}^u\times H$$
has the dimension of a temperature ($x$, $y$, $z$ and $u$ are unknown). 
This gives the system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcc}
y-z+u&=0&\quad[\mathrm M]\\
x+2y+3z+2u&=0&\quad[\mathrm L]\\
-x-y-2z-2u&=1&\quad[\mathrm T]\\
-u&=1&\quad[\Theta]
\end{array}\right.$$
The solution is
$$\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
x&=0\\
y&=1\\
z&=0\\
u&=-1
\end{array}\right.$$
We obtain thus
$$T=\frac{\hbar}{2\pi k_{\mathrm B}}H.$$
The value of $H$ is $H=67.8\, \mathrm{km.s^{-1}.Mpc^{-1}}=2.194\times 10^{-18}\,\mathrm{m.s^{-1}}$. We find a temperature of $T=2.67\times10^{-30}\,\mathrm K$.

Comment: Is this equivalent to the value given here? http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/7-deSitterv2.pdf

Comment: @Anixx. Yes, it is of the same order.